# Controlling contents of a <div> in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page with the following html:

```
<div ng-controller="TraceController">
    <div ng-repeat="trace in traces">
        <div>{{ trace }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="DetailedTraceController">
// I want this content to be defined by the clicking of the above.
</div>
```

I have already populated `traces` with an array of data.  What I would like to do now is to make another `$http` call based on the clicking of the individual `trace` elements.

The question is which is the most correct element to use for my `trace` element?  `<a>` or just a `<div>`?

Also, what would be the most angular way to then trigger a call to the DetailedTraceController to then call another `$http` method with the trace details from above?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uySHJ9?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this was with the following:

```
<div ng-controller="TraceController">
    <div ng-repeat="trace in traces">
        <div ng-click="clickTrace(trace)">{{ trace }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which then set up a method call to `clickTrace` with the trace in question.